# Why is the Cloud Logging receiveTimestamp is in the past?

Tags: google-cloud-logging

Windows event logs are forwarded by the Ops Agent (v2.34) to Cloud Logging. Interestingly, the `receiveTimestamp` of the logs are 1 hour in the past (data below). The expected receiveTimestamp would be a few seconds later, because of the delay in sending the message. What is going on here?

Windows event log timestamp

```xml
..
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-07-03T15:07:16.6620321Z" /> 
..
```

Cloud logging event timestamps

```json
..
  TimeCreated: "2023-07-03 16:07:16 +0100" -- The server is UTC+1, the Ops Agent likely changed the time format here
...
timestamp: "2023-07-03T15:07:16Z"  -- Timestamp matches the UTC timestamp of the Event
..
receiveTimestamp: "2023-07-03T14:07:18.456986121Z" -- Google timestamp is 1 hour earlier?
..
```

I'm raising the issue here, because this appears to affect the user-defined log-based metrics. The metrics don't process any logs, because the logs are from the "future":

> "The log entries that are displayed might be counted late or might not be counted at all, because they are time-stamped too far in the past or future. If a log entry is received by Cloud Logging more than 24 hours in the past **or 10 minutes in the future**, then the log entry won't be counted in the log-based metric."
> Source: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/troubleshooting#slow-startup

I tried deploying a similar setup in another project. Funny enough, this works as expected. The `receiveTimestamp` closely resembles the event timestamp and log-based metrics process my logs.

Comment: The UTC to local date translations in the fluent-bit package appear to ignore DST, causing the date times to shift. I've proposed a [fluent-bit fix](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/pull/8386) recently.